# UITableViewCell bring to front with animation. IOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation

Hi could anyone help me I would like my UITableView cell to animate and zoom to center of my screen, it's kinda like UIAlert but what i need to present is the cell itself.

this is the initial page I have, I tapped the first row of my UITableView
[image]

after I tapped my cell I would like it to animate to center , I need to make a transition that my cell is actually animating to center like this
[image]

could anyone help me please?

this is all I have at the moment

```
 func bringToFront(viewsToAnimate:Array<AnyObject>,duration:Double,delay:Double){
        let scaleTrans = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.3,1.3)

        for views in viewsToAnimate {
            UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, delay: delay, options: .CurveLinear, animations: { () -> Void in
                (views as! UIView).transform = scaleTrans
            }, completion:nil)
        }
    }
```

this function is just zooming.

ps. don't worry about the button `cancel` and `ok` how it appear and disappear

Could anyone help me achieve this? any suggestion and input is well appreciated thanks in advance!

Comment: just a thought...i'm new to swift, so i cant help you achieve this, but i have an idea...put everything inside the cell in a view and pin it to the cell edges..then update those constraints to bring the view to the centre and front...

Comment: @MeharoofNajeeb ohh worth a try. I'll let you know if it works thanks!

Comment: whats wrong with that transform? is it not showing?

Comment: @DavidYangLiu the transform is working fine but i couldn't get the cell to move outside the tableview

Comment: @MeharoofNajeeb sorry for late reply but nah its not possible cos the view is inside the tableview like the cell.contentview. But i have thing in mind that i think would fix this.  I'll add the answer here later. Thanks man!

Comment: @CaffeineShots glad to be of help...post the answer once you get it...